# How do I enable two finger right click in Kubuntu + GNOME?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, touchpad

I just installed GNOME to replace KDE in Kubuntu, and I can't figure out how to do two finger right click by tapping the touchpad. Additionally, I just discovered that I can't tap to click either.

Comment: what is your 0S??

Comment: I am using Debian Linux 64 Bit... i just installed it a few days ago for the first time and was having trouble with this =)

Comment: No problem K7AAY. I just posted it here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543704/how-do-i-enable-two-finger-right-click-in-ubuntu-gnome/543705#543705 . Thanks for pointing me to the correct forum.

Comment: @K7AAY My bad! I actually am not using Debian. My OS is called Kubuntu. However, the KDE desktop manager broke so I installed Gnome on top of it. Sorry for running y'all in circles.

Comment: @Corey Levinson  Requested reopening and edited original question (which you can do, too, with [edit] ) to show it's Kubuntu + GNOME. You can also delete each of your comments above with irrelevant info by clicking _Delete_ after the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Install GNOME Tweaks. In *GNOME Tweaks* > *Keyboard & Mouse*, make sure under "*Mouse Click Emulation*" you select '**Fingers**'.

Then open *Settings* > *Mouse/Touchpad*, and then tick the check box "*Tap to Click*" and then tap to click and two finger tap to right click is working again.

Comment: There is no need to install synaptics. This can be enabled with default libinput.